# How to test exceptions in lab?

Tags: hapi.js

I'm writing test cases using [lab](https://github.com/hapijs/lab) and I would like to test whether or not an exception is thrown from my plugin. The problem is, hapi allows the exception to bubble up while also setting the response to internal server error 500 which causes my test to fail.

We can test for this response `expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(500)` but the test will still fail.

I can't use try/catch around `server.inject` because the exception is thrown asynchronously.

How do I use lab to test for exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An error thrown inside a handler is caught by the `domain` on the `request` object. You can test for the presence of that a couple of different ways.

I'm not particularly happy with either of these ideas but they do both work. Hopefully someone else knows a better way.

**The plugin**

```
exports.register = function (server, options, next) {

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            throw new Error('You should test for this');

            reply();
        }
    });

    next();
}
```

**The test**

```
describe('Getting the homepage', function () {

  it('Throws an error', function (done) {

    server.inject({url: '/'}, function (resp) {

      var error = resp.request.response._error;

      expect(error).to.be.an.instanceof(Error);
      expect(error.message).to.equal('Uncaught error: You should test for this');
      done();

    });
  });
});
```

---

**Alternative**

If you don't like the idea of accessing the private `_error` property (as above), you can add a listener to the `domain` and store the error yourself on the request `object`.

```
server.ext('onPreHandler', function (request, reply) {

    request.domain.on('error', function (error) {
        request.caughtError = error;
    });

    reply.continue();
});
```

**The test**

```
describe('Getting the homepage', function () {

  it('Throws an error', function (done) {

    server.inject({url: '/'}, function (resp) {

      var error = resp.request.caughtError;

      expect(error).to.be.an.instanceof(Error);
      expect(error.message).to.equal('Uncaught error: You should test for this');
      done();

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Matt, thanks for your help! I just tried out your solution and the problem is the exception is still making it out which causes my test to fail. What I need to do is make sure my test catches the exception then check to make sure the exception is what we expect. Is there some way to tap into the domain and re-channel the exception into our test to be caught?

Comment: More specific question, when we add the listener to request.domain.on('error', callback) can we also stop the propagation of that exception right there and then?

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I had to move my 'onPreHandler' extension before my plugin.